# How can I make a button visible in one activity when clicking a button in another? - Android

Tags: android, button, android-activity, visibility

So I have a simple quiz game where the user writes his answer on an EditText and then click the buton **"Check"** to check if his answer is correct. If his answer is correct, **the button on the other activity will be visible**. What i want to know is that, is it possible to control an object on another activity? In vb.net you can just simply do this by "*formName.Button1.Visible=true*". What about Android? Thanks for your help **:)**

Comment: Only one activity is visible at a time. Did you mean fragment maybe?

Comment: Where is the "other" activity? Anyways, unless you have a weird situation, you should start (or go back) to the other activity, sending some flag as an extra in the intent.

Answer (score 1):

**Answers the Question**

Add a flag to your starting intent that is consumed by the receiving acitivty

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {
    public static final String EXTRA_IS_CORRECT = "extra_is_correct";

    private void startActivityB() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_IS_CORRECT, true);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And then in ActivityB where you are displaying the button

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent startingIntent = getIntent();
    boolean isCorrect = intent.getBooleanExtra(ActivityA.EXTRA_IS_CORRECT, false);

    if(isCorrect) {
        // hide/show button
    }
}
```

**What you should do**

Look into fragments and have 1 activity hosting 2 fragments. Then the activity can talk directly to each fragment without sending intents.